# Can ganache with butter be frozen, thawed and reused?

Tags: freezing, ganache

I have made a batch of ganache with butter in it. The recipe was supposed to be for chocolates, but I want to now use it on top of a cake. Can I freeze it, then thaw and use it in about a weeks time?

Comment: Freeze before or after it's on the cake?

Answer (score 3):

I have frozen ganache and used it later as a topping with no problems. Just ensure that it is warmed enough to become semi-liquid before you use it for topping your cake.

As a note - it's also delicious scooped frozen from the container. Perfect with icecream.

Comment: I've never actually found it necessary to freeze ganache -- just refrigerated it. Good to know! Out of curiosity, how do you warm it up? Microwave, or just let it sit out for a day?

Comment: @kitukwfyer, just a gentle microwave, but I usually bring it to room temp first.